# Issue with multiplication in php

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php 

include 'dbconnection.php'; 

 $Days=0; $Kg=0.00; $Wage=0.00; 
 $Rate=0.00;  $KgDivDays=0.00; $ExtraKgs = 0.00;
 $WageExtraKgs=0.00; $TotalWages=0.00;
 $BalanceWage=0.00; $EightPerc=0.00; $TwelvePerc=0.00; $ThreePerc=0.00;
 $Advances=0.00; $FestAdvances=0.00;

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT EmployeeName,DailyRate FROM employees");


//fetch the data from the database 
try{
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row{'EmployeeName'}."</td>";
    $Rate=$row{'DailyRate'};
    //echo "<td>".$Rate."</td>";
    //echo "<td style = 'display:none'>".$row{'DailyRate'}."</td>";
    //echo $Rate;
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='Days' id='Days".$i."' onChange='CalcWage(".$i.");'/></td>";
    echo "<td id='Wage".$i."'>".$Wage."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='Kg' id='Kg".$i."' onChange='CalcAmount(".$i.");'/></td>";
    echo "<td id='KgDivDays".$i."'>".$KgDivDays."</td>";
    echo "<td id='ExtraKgs".$i."'>".$ExtraKgs."</td>";
    echo "<td id='WageExtraKgs".$i."'>".$WageExtraKgs."</td>";
    echo "<td id='TotalWages".$i."'>".$TotalWages."</td>";
    echo "<td id='EightPerc".$i."'>".$EightPerc."</td>";
    echo "<td id='TwelvePerc".$i."'>".$TwelvePerc."</td>";
    echo "<td id='ThreePerc".$i."'>".$ThreePerc."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='Advances' id='Advances".$i."'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='FestAdvances' id='FestAdvances".$i."' onChange='CalcBalanceWage(".$i.");'/></td>";
    echo "<td id='BalanceWage".$i."'>".$BalanceWage."</td>";
    $i++;
}
}
catch(Exception $e)
{echo "error".$e;}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function CalcWage(i){
    var Days=document.getElementById('Days'+i).value;
    var php_rate = "<?php echo $Rate; ?>";
    //alert(php_rate);
    var Wage=parseFloat(Days*php_rate);
    document.getElementById('Wage'+i).innerHTML= Wage;
    return Wage;
}

function CalcAmount(i){
    var Kg=document.getElementById('Kg'+i).value;
    var Days=document.getElementById('Days'+i).value;
    var KgDivDays = parseFloat(Days*4);
    document.getElementById('KgDivDays'+i).innerHTML= KgDivDays;
    var ExtraKgs=Kg-KgDivDays;
    document.getElementById('ExtraKgs'+i).innerHTML= ExtraKgs;
    var WageExtraKgs=ExtraKgs*50;
    document.getElementById('WageExtraKgs'+i).innerHTML= WageExtraKgs;
    var BasicSal = CalcWage(i);
    var TotalWages= BasicSal + WageExtraKgs;
    document.getElementById('TotalWages'+i).innerHTML= TotalWages;
    var EightPerc= parseFloat(BasicSal * 0.08);
    document.getElementById('EightPerc'+i).innerHTML= EightPerc;
    var TwelvePerc= parseFloat(BasicSal * 0.12);
    document.getElementById('TwelvePerc'+i).innerHTML= TwelvePerc;
    var ThreePerc= parseFloat(BasicSal * 0.03);
    document.getElementById('ThreePerc'+i).innerHTML= ThreePerc;
    return TotalWages;
}

function CalcBalanceWage(i){
    var Advances=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Advances'+i).value);
    var FestAdvances=parseFloat(document.getElementById('FestAdvances'+i).value);
    var TotWage = CalcAmount(i); 
    var BasSal =  CalcWage(i); 
    var Deductions = parseFloat(Advances+FestAdvances+(BasSal*0.08));
    var BalanceWage=parseFloat(TotWage-Deductions);
    document.getElementById('BalanceWage'+i).innerHTML= BalanceWage;
    return BalanceWage;
}

</script>

<?php
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Question: I have a database table for employees and here i am querying to get the employee name and their respective dailyrates. In my table I have daily rates 500, 600 and 600 for the 3 employees. When I echo the respective rates on my while loop it displays the correct value against each employee. However, when I multiply by Days it seems to always multiply by 600 (although the 1st value in my db is 500). Appreciate if you can point me to where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Look at the source code that is being output to the browser. Pretty sure `php_rate` is 600.

Comment: Can you cut the code down to a minimal test case which shows the problem you're facing?

Comment: Why are you mixing javascript and php logic? Separate into a .js file for maintainability

Comment: Check the value of `$Rate=$row{'DailyRate'};`

Comment: I've checked the value of $Rate=$row{'DailyRate'}; using an echo on the next line of code itself. and it shows 500, 600 and 600.. but when multiplying it always multiplies by 600... and yes, i will separate out the javascripts once i am done with the logic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you get `php_rate = 600`.

The **last iteration** in your loop makes `$Rate = 600 ;`. So you use only the last value of the variable.

You must either store your rates in array and the use them, or just do the multiplication inside your `while` loop.

Another option: pass the rate as the function parameter.

```
onClick = 'CalcWage({$i}, {$Rate});'

function CalcWage(i, php_rate){
    var Days=document.getElementById('Days'+i).value;
    //var php_rate = "<?php echo $Rate; ?>";
    //alert(php_rate);
    var Wage=parseFloat(Days*php_rate);
    document.getElementById('Wage'+i).innerHTML= Wage;
    return Wage;
}
```

Also, what is wrong with using `try - catch` block? What exception are you trying to catch? `mysql_fetch_array` does not throw any.

More suggestions:

- Access array data using square brackets. `$array[$i]` and so on.
- Do not use `mysql_*`, it is deprecated. `mysqli_*` or `PDO` are your friends now.
- Variable names should start with a small letter. `$rate`, `$wage` (in JS too)
- When concatenating a string, you do not have to break it into pieces. You could just put variables like that: `echo "Look, I am so usable here! Name: {$variable}" ;`

Comment: thank you very much for the advise. I will sure look into these. I am new to programming in PHP and your advise will definitely help me. Also I updated my code and its working fine. Thanks again. :-)